# Каким образом лучше всего остановить или включить показ продукта из админ панели?

Tags: php, laravel

В админ панели должна быть способность остановить показ продукта (или включить).

Как лучше всего это сделать ?

Есть ли возможность обойтись без нового столбца в базе данных (если нету и это подойдет)?

Программа написана на Laravel (*soft delete* уже используется для другой возможности).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, добавить поле `enabled tinyint` и чекать его.

Answer (score 0):

лучший способ, как уже писали выше сделать новый столбец published или active и внеси его в локальный скоуп
а в админке просто добавить чекбокс